# Spawning hundreds of Lambda processes but waiting for them all to finish

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently using AWS Step Functions in a "queue watcher" setup.

I have an initial Lambda that spawns hundreds of ID's that are added to an SQS queue, which is then consumed by a "Worker" Lambda. When the "Worker" lambda has consumed the queue I need to run a "Logout" Lambda to expire a ticket.

The problem I'm having is sometimes the logout happens before the queue is empty.

Is there a better solution to this? I've looked into callbacks but it doesn't seem usable in this scenario? Passing the payload through Step Functions instead of SQS isn't possible either due to payload limits.

Thanks,

Step Function:

[image]

Flow Chart of Lambdas:

[image]

Comment: Can the messages producer mark the last message somehow? This way the worker lambda would execute the Logout action upon receiving the marked msg?

Comment: I like this idea, the only problem is the "Worker" can produce more messages as it starts to page data as it extracts from the API. I can't predict the number of pages as the API is a bit rubbish and doesn't present any paging info. I have to extract in batches of 100 until I get an empty batch.

Comment: "The problem I'm having is sometimes the logout happens before the queue is empty." Is this because the final message(s) are still being processed? You should check that the queue has no message available, and also that there are no messages in-flight.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm looking for both visible and nonvisible message.